Put a grid next to a Frame in UWP
I'm coding an UWP app. I want to put a Grid right next to a frame.
Here is MainPage.XAML:
<Page
    x:Class="Project_NewSpartan.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Project_NewSpartan"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <!-- Define rows for the layout -->
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <!-- First row for the AppTitleBar -->
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <!-- Second row for the NavigationFrame -->
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <!-- Second row for the Frame content -->
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>

        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- AppTitleBar placed in the first row -->
        <Frame x:Name="TitlebarFrame" Grid.Row="0"/>
        
        <!-- NavigationRailFrame placed in the second row -->
        <Frame x:Name="NavigationFrame" Grid.Row="1"/>

        <!-- Main content placed in the third row -->
        <Frame x:Name="MainFrame" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>

        <Grid Grid.Row="2" MaxWidth="200" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Background="Red"></Grid>
    </Grid>
</Page>

So, what I want is this:
|TitlebarFrame               |
|NavigationFrame             |
|WebView         |The Grid   |
So I want that the webview take automatticaly the available space AFTER the grid take the 200 width. How can I do that?
Please help me   :,(

MaxWidth doesn't actually reserve any space; MinWidth does that.

"AFTER the grid take the 200 width", First, there is nothing in your grid, and the width of the grid will always be 0. It cannot reach 200. Do you want the grid to appear when the Page is enlarged?

Gerry Schmitz found the answer: put MinWidth to 200
